# Using cp, what is the difference between copying to DEST and DIRECTORY?

Tags: cp

In the man page for `cp`, what is the difference between copying to DEST and DIRECTORY?

`cp` copies a SOURCE to a DEST and SOURCES to a DIRECTORY.

```
   SYNOPSIS

   cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
   cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 5):

With `DEST` it is assuming you are naming the file name and path (and therefore directory) of the destination file.  With `DIRECTORY` you are just listing which directory the destination file will be in, while preserving the `SOURCE` name.

Answer (score 2):

If SOURCE is just one file, the difference depends on what the command finds: If there is a directory DEST, SOURCE is copied into it, preserving the name. If it does not exist or is a file, DEST is interpreted as new name to use, eventually overriding DEST if it is a file.

If you have multiple SOURCES, DEST can only be a directory, since copying multiple files into one dest file would only preserve the last copied file and be rather useless for almost all cases.

A copy command:

```
cp s1 s2 s3 d1 d2 d3
```

would look as if it would make some sense, since an even number of names could match s1 -> d1, s2 -> d2 ... , but think of shell expansion:

```
cp *
```

could result in different interpretation, depending on the number of files matched by *. So if you use multiple files, the last is always assumed to be a directory. If it doesn't exist, you get an error message.